# How to efficiently sum and mean 2D NumPy arrays by id?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d array `a` and a 1d array `b`. I want to compute the sum of rows in array `a` group by each id in `b`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]])
b = np.array([0,1,0])
count = len(b)
ls = list(set(b))
res = np.zeros((len(ls),a.shape[1]))
for i in ls:
    res[i] = np.array([a[x] for x in range(0,count) if b[x] == i]).sum(axis=0)
print res
```

I got the printed result as:

```
[[ 5.  7.  9.]
 [ 2.  3.  4.]]
```

What I want to do is, since the 1st and 3rd elements of `b` are `0`, I perform `a[0]+a[2]`, which is `[5, 7, 9]` as one row of the results. Similarly, the 2nd element of `b` is `1`, so that I perform `a[1]`, which is `[2, 3, 4]` as another row of the results.

But it seems my implementation is quite slow for large array. Is there any better implementation?

I know there is a `bincount` function in `numpy`. But it seems only supports 1d array.
Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: I don't get quite exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @s_vishnu I have updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: So you want to add all rows which have  corresponding `0` and all rows which have `1` ?

Comment: @s_vishnu Yes. But more general, there can be much more than 2 ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You can use [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html), which works for ndarrays of generic dimensions, unlike `np.bincount` that expects only 1D arrays  -

```
np.add.at(res, b, a)
```

Sample run -

```
In [40]: a
Out[40]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [41]: b
Out[41]: array([0, 1, 0])

In [45]: res = np.zeros((b.max()+1, a.shape[1]), dtype=a.dtype)

In [46]: np.add.at(res, b, a)

In [47]: res
Out[47]: 
array([[5, 7, 9],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

To compute `mean` values, we need to use `np.bincount` to get the counts per label/tag and then divide with those along each row, like so -

```
In [49]: res/np.bincount(b)[:,None].astype(float)
Out[49]: 
array([[ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5],
       [ 2. ,  3. ,  4. ]])
```

Generalizing to handle `b` that are not necessarily in sequence from `0`, we could make it generic and put in a nice little function to handle summations and averages in a cleaner way, like so -

```
def groupby_addat(a, b, out="sum"):
    unqb, tags, counts = np.unique(b, return_inverse=1, return_counts=1)
    res = np.zeros((tags.max()+1, a.shape[1]), dtype=a.dtype)
    np.add.at(res, tags, a)

    if out=="mean":
        return unqb, res/counts[:,None].astype(float)
    elif out=="sum":
        return unqb, res
    else:
        print "Invalid output"
        return None
```

Sample run -

```
In [201]: a
Out[201]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [202]: b
Out[202]: array([ 5, 10,  5])

In [204]: b_ids, means = groupby_addat(a, b, out="mean")

In [205]: b_ids
Out[205]: array([ 5, 10])

In [206]: means
Out[206]: 
array([[ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5],
       [ 2. ,  3. ,  4. ]])
```

**Approach #2**

We could also make use of [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) and might be more performant -

```
def groupby_addreduceat(a, b, out="sum"):
    sidx = b.argsort()
    sb = b[sidx]
    spt_idx =np.concatenate(([0], np.flatnonzero(sb[1:] != sb[:-1])+1, [sb.size]))
    sums = np.add.reduceat(a[sidx],spt_idx[:-1])

    if out=="mean":
        counts = spt_idx[1:] - spt_idx[:-1]
        return sb[spt_idx[:-1]], sums/counts[:,None].astype(float)
    elif out=="sum":
        return sb[spt_idx[:-1]], sums
    else:
        print "Invalid output"
        return None
```

Sample run -

```
In [201]: a
Out[201]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [202]: b
Out[202]: array([ 5, 10,  5])

In [207]: b_ids, means = groupby_addreduceat(a, b, out="mean")

In [208]: b_ids
Out[208]: array([ 5, 10])

In [209]: means
Out[209]: 
array([[ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5],
       [ 2. ,  3. ,  4. ]])
```

Comment: Yes. That is it! BTW, I also need to compute the mean in the same way. Is there any similar function for the mean values? Thank you!

Comment: @pfc Check out the edits please. I took the liberty to edit the question title accordingly. Hope that's okay. Feel free to edit further if needed.

Comment: Thank you. I met with another problem. In fact the array b may not be [0, 1], but instead [100, 101]. In this case I met with the out-of-bound error. How can I fix it? Thank you so much for your kind patience.

Comment: @pfc Are you doing the initialization as suggested in this post - `res = np.zeros((b.max()+1, a.shape[1]), dtype=a.dtype)`?

Comment: Thank you. You do solve my problem. Thank you for your kindness!

Answer (score 3):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) was made to address problems exactly of this kind in an efficiently vectorized and general manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique_b, mean_a = npi.group_by(b).mean(a)
```

Note that this solution is general in the sense that it provides a rich set of standard reduction function (sum, min, mean, median, argmin, and so on), axis keywords if you need to work with different axes, and also the ability to group by more complicated things than just positive integer arrays, such as the elements of multidimensional arrays of arbitrary dtype.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
# this caches the complicated O(NlogN) part of the operations
groups = npi.group_by(b)
# all these subsequent operations have the same low vectorized O(N) cost
unique_b, mean_a = groups.mean(a)
unique_b, sum_a = groups.sum(a)
unique_b, min_a = groups.min(a)
```

Comment: Also thank you so much. I have tested. Your implementation is the fastest among all the methods I have tested. Thank you and I do recommend this implementation!!!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Internally these functions use reduceat for their reductions, which also proved much faster for me than addat in my benchmarks (must be some numpy implementation detail; i dont see a fundamental reason for it). So Divakar's updated reduceat solution should be of a similar order of performance, as it goes through the same steps as this library.